# Displaying the result of an SQL query in an HTML table

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm stuck for a while, I try to display the result of a variable that executes a sql query in an html table, here is my code;

```
$REQUT = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('DISTINCT r.prod , r.di, COUNT(*) as Result')
->from('tabl r')
->groupBy('r.di')
->orderBy('Result ASC') ;

$REQUT->fetchArray();
```

PS : I work in symfony, I am looking to have a view like mysql

Comment: Yeah, I was about to translate too. - use http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/R%C3%A9sultat%20sql%20dans%20un%20tableau%20html

Comment: Urk, someone got rid of the generic symfony tag.  Are you using 1.x or 2.x?  You'll want to adjust the tag as appropriate.

Comment: @Charles regarding the query it seems to be doctrine 1, so it's symfony1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the result set. I don't know this particular API, but assuming it works similarly to others:

```
$REQUT = // all that query stuff
while($ROW = $REQUT->fetchArray()) {
    // do something
    var_dump($ROW);
}
```

Comment: this is what var_dump($REQUT->fetchArray();
) displays :

    array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(4) "22" ["prod"]=> string(2) "15" ["di"]=> string(4) "A12" ["Result"]=> string(1) "1" } }



And I want to display this array in html table. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to display as a html table...

```
 $REQUT = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('DISTINCT r.prod , r.di, COUNT(*) as Result')
->from('tabl r')
->groupBy('r.di')
->orderBy('Result ASC') ;

echo "<table>";
while($ROW = $REQUT->fetchArray()) 
{

echo "<tr><td>".$ROW["prod"]."<td>";
echo "<td>".$ROW["di"]."<td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hi
it returns Undefined index: prod in a infinit loop!

Comment: I'm really lost, can someone help me?